# Imprimir laberinto por medio de sus coordenadas

Tags: c

buenas.

Tengo un laberinto así:

```
*************
*          F*
*  **** * * *
*  **   * * *
*  ** *** * *
*S          *
*************
```

Y me gustaría imprimirlo en el programa por medio de bucles, pero estoy obteniendo un problema el cual es el siguiente:

```
laberinto.c:30:39: error: invalid initializer
char laberinto[ANCHURA][ALTURA]=getc(f);
```

El código que se está utilizando es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ALTURA (7)
#define ANCHURA (13)

void imprimirLaberinto(char laberinto[ANCHURA][ALTURA]){
  int i;
  int j;

  for (i = 0; i < ANCHURA; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < ALTURA; j++) {
      printf("%c ", laberinto[i][j]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
  }

}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  int i;
  int j;

  FILE *f; //define que variable va a ser el archivo

    f=fopen(argv[1],"r"); // Se selecciona el archivo y su modo (lectura, escritura, etc.)

  char laberinto[ANCHURA][ALTURA]=getc(f);

         if( f==NULL ){
               printf("Error al abrir el laberinto\n"); // Condicional que checa si el archivo e*iste
         }
       else
          {
                imprimirLaberinto(laberinto);
          }
}
```

Espero si me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Del manual de `getc( )`:

> #### int getc( FILE *stream )
>
> Reads the next character from stream and returns it as an unsigned char cast to an int, or EOF on end of file or error.

Lee **un solo caracter**, y tu lo estás intentando utilizar para que lea **una secuencia de caracteres; mas de uno**.

Intentando cambiar lo menos posible tu código, podrías utilizar un bucle (como el que ya tienes) para realizar la lectura:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  FILE *f;
  int error = 1;
  char laberinto[ANCHURA][ALTURA];
  int i, j, readed;

  f = fopen( argv[1], "r" );

  if( f != NULL ) {
    for( i = 0; i < ANCHURA; i++ ) {
      for( j = 0; j < ALTURA; j++ ) {
        readed = getc( f );
        if( readed == EOF ) {
          error = 1;
          break;
        }

        laberinto[i][j] = readed;
      }
    }
    error = 0;
  }

  if( error != 0 ) {
    printf( "Error al abrir el laberinto\n" );
  } else {
    imprimirLaberinto( laberinto );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Se ha mejorado un poco el control de errores, y lo único *extraño* es la palabra `break`, que sirve para **salir del bucle actual**. No tiene sentido continuar leyendo se se terminó el archivo o se produjo algún error.

Comment: Vale, lo comprendo. Pero la cosa es que voy a estar utilizando el archivo con sus coordenadas (`altura` y `anchura`) por eso mismo quiero definir los contenidos de este arreglo como un archivo para luego poder agregarle una funcion recursiva que busque su solución. Cómo podría definir ese arreglo?

Comment: Marqué tu respuesta como correcta ya que apunta al problema que tiene mi código.

Comment: No te entiendo. Tu *arreglo* es de 2D, y el archivo siempre va a ser plano (1D). Si quieres acceder al archivo, simulando las 2D, tienes que usar otras funciones: [`int fseek( FILE *stream, long offset, int whence );`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseek.3.html)

Comment: También puedes leerlo secuencialmente, como haces ahora, pero ignorando el valor leido hasta que llegues a la *celda* que te interese.

Comment: Y ¿Cómo haría eso? me podrías dar un ejemplo por favor? lo apreciaría mucho.